# Spring '15 @TestSetup doesn't work

Tags: apex, unit-test, spring15

This test is supposed to succeed in a Spring'15 org, but doesn't.

```
@isTest
private class MyTest {

    static Integer value = null;

    @isTest
    static void testMethod() {
      System.assertNotEquals(null, value);
    }


    @TestSetup
    static void setSourceData() {
        value = 17;
    }
}
```

Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The @TestSetup notation isn't meant to be used for the setting of private variables as far as I'm aware. You can **insert records** with it and use those in your tests. For more information, see: https://developer.salesforce.com/releases/release/Spring15/TestClasses